# How to loop through columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with many metric columns all containing float output. I need to round them all to four digits. I want to loop through all the columns to do this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4), columns=['a','b','c','d'])

metrics = test_df.columns
metrics = metrics.tolist()

for x in metrics:
    test_df.x = np.round(test_df.x, 4)
```

However, this gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import functools
test_df.apply(functools.partial(np.round, decimals=4))
```

if you want to iterate through columns, it's straightforward:

```
for c in test_df.columns:
    test_df[c] = np.round(test_df[c], 4)
```

what you tried to do that's busted has to do with attribute access in python. when you try to do `test_df.x`, that `x` has absolutely nothing to do with the `x` in your `for` loop. this would have the same result:

```
for unused_value in metrics:
    test_df.x = ...
```